# Reinforcement learning with Super Mario not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

After experimenting with the Cart Pole from openai gym, I wanted to try something a bit more advanced reinforcement learning and went on with Super Mario Bros NES. Using a similar setup doesn't seem to yield the results I was expecting though, and Mario doesn't seem to learn anything.

I have been using retro gym to emulate the environment and writing some custom wrappers for actions, observations and reward (code for these are at the bottom) and these seem to yield what I was expecting. For reinforcement learning I have been using TensorFlow for the network model and the DQN agent from Keras-RL with an epsilon greedy Q policy, and after many hours of training Mario is still unable to jump high enough to get over the initial obstacles.

Code for reinforcement learning:

```
import retro
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from wrapper import wrapper

env = retro.make('SuperMarioBros-Nes', use_restricted_actions=retro.Actions.DISCRETE)
env = wrapper(env)

states = 70
actions = 4
train_size = 5000000

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,10,7)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=train_size, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=100000, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

model = build_model(states, actions)

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=train_size, visualize=True, verbose=1)

dqn.save_weights('weights/MarioWeights.h5f', overwrite=True)
```

I have tried tuning network architecture and target update rate, different policies, exploration vs. exploitation, observation space, reward and target update rate, but little seems to change and reward converges at very low values after a while.

Code for wrappers:

```
class ObservationWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.env = env

    def observation(self, obs):
        ### STATE MODIFICATION ###
        ram = self.env.get_ram()                                                # Grab ram data
        tiles = SMB.get_tiles(ram)                                              # Grab dict with all tiles on the screen
        t_list = list(tiles.values())                                           # Convert to list
        ct_list = np.asarray(self.chunkify(t_list))                             # Convert to array with image dimensions
        try:
            m_x = int(np.where(ct_list == 170)[1])
        except:
            m_x = 3
        return ct_list[4:14, m_x:m_x+7]                                         # Crop to ROI

    def chunkify(self, list, n=16):                                             # Function to extract rows, or chunks, of 16 values from the image
        c_list = []
        row = []
        count = 0
        for i in list:
            row.append(i.value)
            count += 1
            if count%16 == 0:
                c_list.append(row)
                row = []
        return c_list


class ActionWrapper(gym.ActionWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.action_list = [0, 6, 18, 24]#, 3]                                  # NOOP, RIGHT, JUMP, RIGHT + JUMP, LEFT

    def action(self, act):
        return self.action_list[act]

class BasicWrapper(gym.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.env = env
        self.total_reward = 0
        self.max_reward = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.mario_old_pos = [40,176]                                           # Starting position of Mario on env.reset()
        self.t_old = 400                                                        # Counting down from 400

    def reset_init(self):
        self.total_reward = 0
        self.max_reward = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.mario_old_pos = [40,176]
        self.t_old = 400

    def check_alive(self, ram):                                                 # Check if dying or dead
        if SMB._is_alive(ram):
            return 0
        else:
            return -15

    def step(self, action):
        next_state, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)

        ram = self.env.get_ram()

        done = SMB._got_flag(ram)                                               # Check if Mario finished level and got flag
        mario_pos = SMB.get_mario_location_in_level(ram)                        # Grab Mario location in level

        vx = (int(mario_pos[0]) - int(self.mario_old_pos[0])) * 2
        if vx > 10:
            vx = 0

        self.mario_old_pos = mario_pos

        d = self.check_alive(ram)

        timer = info.get('time')
        c = timer - self.t_old
        self.t_old = timer

        reward = vx + vy + c + d

        self.total_reward += reward
        if self.total_reward > self.max_reward:
            self.max_reward = self.total_reward

        # Reset if Mario is stuck
        if self.frame > 100:
            if d < 0 or (self.total_reward < self.max_reward - 0.1*self.total_reward):
                self.reset_init()
                self.env.reset()

        self.frame += 1

        return next_state, reward, done, info
```

The reward here is stolen from https://github.com/Kautenja/gym-super-mario-bros, while the observations are inspired by https://chrispresso.io/AI_Learns_To_Play_SMB_Using_GA_And_NN.

I feel like I am missing something essential. Any suggestions for how to proceed?